# Magenta drop shadow on black text, when printing PDF

Tags: pdf, printing

Took my PDF file to a professional printers who returned my document with a haze around all the text.

A simple black and white document became one with a magenta drop shadow that hurts even my eyes. Any ideas why this may have happened?

PDF looked perfect on screen, so I refuse to believe there was an issue with the file.

Photo here:

[image: Drop shadow on text]

Comment: Did the professional printers hear your complaint? What did they say?

Comment: ...that the problem was with my PDF, and not their "£60,000 printers". It prints fine anywhere else, so I don't believe it! Who knew printing black text on a white background could be so complex!

Comment: that looks like a misaligned CMYK print head. A £60k printer still needs the heads/drum/whatever technology they use aligning. Did they print as black and white/greyscale?

Comment: I don't know what they did, to be honest! You'd think they'd do a test print to see if the printed sheet matched the PDF, right? Or is that too much logic?

Comment: 60 grand printer, 4-bob employees. All 4 colours are mis-aligned, btw. Take it back as "not fit for purpose", but keep half a dozen for if you need to take them to court.

Comment: PDF is *deliberately* designed to look and print in a manner independent of application software, hardware, and operating systems; so I really doubt there's something wrong with your file. If the file looks good everywhere but on their prints, the problem is with their gear.

Comment: Thanks for the reassurance. As it happens, there's not much I can do about it on this occasion – certainly my first and last visit there.